# Error after updating jar using jar uf

Tags: java, jar

I have updated a jar file using the command `java uf` in my windows machine. After updating, I unzipped my jar and able to see that my changes got updated in the class files.(I decompiled and saw). But when I use the jar in my application I am getting `NoClassDefFounderror` for the particular class I have updated. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

Just a possibility.
Does you class(that you have changed) use any third party class(jar) that you have not added part of your jar or not refereed from inside of your jar.

Comment: No. my changes are so simple. I just commented few lines and added few. No new import has been included.